# How to change Tapku calendar to week view from month view

Tags: iphone, tapku

I am using Tapku calendar that is displaying the month view in it, i want to show the week view in calendar on button click. What changes are required to made and where in the code. Please guide for the above. And ask if anything else required to know to answer the question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer this link.[different types of calendar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=calendar)

Comment: I am working on Tapku calendar and has already implemented the functionality on month view, so can't change to any other now, please share if you have any idea or code for week view in tapku itself.

Comment: Tapku allows monthView only.For weekView use another [library](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui).From this library take weekViewController and relate classes then implement to your current project.

Answer (score 1):

Use in the same view controllers a

1. `@property(nonatomic, strong) TKCalendarDayTimelineView *calendarDayTimelineView;`
2. `@property(nonatomic, strong) TKCalendarMonthTableView *calendarMonthTableView;`
3. `@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger calendarViewType;`

Implement the required delegates: `<TKCalendarDayTimelineViewDelegate>` and `<TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate,TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource>`

After that make a method to hide and show this views:

```
- (IBAction)calendarViewAction:(id)sender
{
 if (self.calendarViewType == 1) {
        [self.calendarDayTimelineView setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        [self.calendarDayTimelineView setHidden:YES];     
    }

    if (self.calendarViewType == 0) {
        [self.calendarMonthTableView setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        [self.calendarMonthTableView setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: hii, in my tapku library there are no such files mentioned above please can you provide the link of those files, i tried from net, downloaded that library, but it is giving Mach Link error. Please guide.

Comment: Did you downlaoded the library from here: https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary and followed the instalation stapes from here https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-Tapku-to-Your-Project-in-XCode-4

Comment: Ya i have done that now it is giving me this error "SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h file not found".

Comment: You have to add the `SenTestingKit.framework` to your project in your app's target > Summary > Linked Frameworks and libraries

Comment: hii, the link you provided is not adding library in the project it is giving error, if i add sen testing kit app doesn't work.

Comment: Hi have you added this framework in your project, please check if it works it is not working in mine,

Comment: I used TapkuLibrary in a project because needed the calendar component and it workes. Can you provide some errors that are shown?

Comment: When i add sen testing kit, then it gives following error. "(Apple Mach-O Linker Error): "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:"

Comment: Can you give me your mail id so that i can send you how i tried to add Tapku library.

Comment: Here you go alexcristea@me.com

Comment: alexcristea@me.com is my email address but you can also try to send it on alex.cristea@ymail.com

Comment: i just saw your mail now, went on lunch, let me check then i revert back to you. thanks for your effort.

Comment: Hey i have added the library successfully but it is giving this "<TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h>" file not found. Please check i  think i am very close. I have added libraries before also but don't know why this is happening this time. Please check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28886/discussion-between-alexcristea-and-iphone)